# while loop needs to repeat when asked

Tags: python, function, while-loop

So for this assignment I am needed to play a game of rock paper scissors. I have all of it done except for when I want to start a new game the scores don't go back to zero. The basics of my code are:

```
x=1
i=1
ps=0
cs=0
while i==1:
    while x==1:
        print("First to 5 wins!")
        #print score
        score(str(ps),str(cs))
        #code for game and the outcomes
        #ending
        if ps!=5 and cs!=5:
            end=yesorno("Would you like to forfeit? (y/n)")
            if end=="y":
                print("You coward!")
                ngc=yesorno("Would you like to start a new game? (y/n)")
                ng=ngc.lower()
                if ng=="y":
                    i=2
                else:
                    i=1
                    x=2
                    input("press enter to exit...")
            
            else:
                i=1
       else:
            if cs==5:
                print("The computer won 5 to "+ps+"...")
                ngc=yesorno("Would you like to start a new game? (y/n)")
                ng=ngc.lower()
                if ng=="y":
                    i=2
                else:
                    i=1
                    x=2
                    input("press enter to exit...")
            else:
                print("The player won 5 to "+str(cs)+"...")
                ngc=yesorno("Would you like to start a new game? (y/n)")
                ng=ngc.lower()
                if ng=="y":
                    i=2
                else:
                    i=1
                    x=2
                    input("press enter to exit...")
```

Comment: You didn't reset the score after getting user input "y", try adding the `ps = 0` and `cs = 0` after the line `if ng == "y"`

Comment: As a side note, as you're learning programming: you should really use *meaningful* variable names to make your code more readable. What are I and x supposed to represent, and what do the values 1 and 2 mean? That's a mystery I'm not inclined to solve...

Answer (score 0):

When you ask if a player wants to start a new game, you should change `i` to `1`, instead of `2`.

In addition, it's possible that you have a mistake in `yesorno` function.

But I recommend you change the structure of your code. Create a function, that starts a new game, for example. And please, use better names for variables:)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if everywhere you handle the new game prompt you put

```
if ng=="y":
    ps = 0
    cs = 0
    i=2
```

Maybe you are not far enough in to learning programming but this is a good opportunity to use a function to reduce code duplication.

As well as this, variables i and x seem like they could be booleans, like

```
while continueGame:
    ...
    # End game code
    continueGame = False
```

If you haven't learnt this stuff yet don't worry about it.